# Expanding new Media Uploader in WordPress 3.5

Tags: attachments, media, attachment-fields-to-edit, media-modal

In current version of WordPress it is quite easy to expand the attachments fields using `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter, but in latest **WordPress 3.5 RC2** it's not working. We can expand it using custom meta fields, but using this requires editing each attachment in Media tb. I was wondering if it is possible to expand fields in **Attachment details** in modal box with Media Library https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPM53.png (sorry for a link but I cannot add image, not enough reputation ;))

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please update your question to reference the current stable release of WordPress 3.5, as RC2 was pre-release software.

Answer (score 3):

You can add inputs and fields to attachments by hooking into `attachment_fields_to_edit`. This will add fields to both the modal as well as the attachment editor. The catch I found is that WordPress (if anyone has experienced differently PLMK) doesn't save the extra fields data so you have to hook into a couple other items.

I have added a code sample to give you add idea of what you could do.

```
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'xf_attachment_fields', 10, 2 );

function xf_attachment_fields( $fields, $post ) {

 $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_link', true);
 $fields['meta_link'] = array(
    'label' => 'More Media Management',
    'input' => 'text',
    'value' => $meta,
     // 'html' => '<div class="meta_link"><input type="text" /></div>',
   'show_in_edit' => true,
 );
 return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'xa_update_attachment_meta', 4);

function xa_update_attachment_meta($attachment){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_link', $attachment['attachments'][$post->ID]['meta_link']);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_save-attachment-compat', 'xa_media_xtra_fields', 0, 1);
function xa_media_xtra_fields() {
  $post_id = $_POST['id'];
  $meta = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id ]['meta_link'];
  update_post_meta($post_id , 'meta_link', $meta);
  clean_post_cache($post_id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I needed to add `return $attachment;` to the `xa_update_attachment_meta` callback, but after that, it worked.

Comment: This thread seems abandoned by its OP, but I'm wondering if all this "compat" stuff is really where it's at in WP 3.5. Is there a new, current (as in "not backward compatible, but by design going forward") method to add this kind of thing in WP 3.5+?

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to use attachment_fields_to_edit, however those fields are also added to the modal window now. You can direct a field to only show up in the modal or only show up on the edit page by using the "show_in_edit" or "show_in_modal" parameters. Both are boolean and both default to true. Take a look at this trac ticket explaining the behavior: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22759#comment:1

You should be aware that they seem to now be prefixed with "compat-field-" in the class names.